# fetch data from two tables on some condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch record when either the `country_of_origin` is same for two tables or when the country_of_origin in the table is equal to `Any Country`.

For which I have used the below query:

```
SELECT `tbui`.`user_id`,`tbui`.`first_name`,`tbui`.`last_name`,`tbui`.`education_level`,`tbui`.`sex`,`tbui`.`country_of_origin`,`tbui`.`city`,`tbui`.`state`,`tbui`.`country`,`tbui`.`occupation`,`tbui`.`about`,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) as age
FROM `tb_preference_dropdown` as `tbpda`
LEFT JOIN `tb_user_answers` as `tbua` ON `tbpda`.`question_id` = `tbua`.`question_id`
LEFT JOIN `tb_preference_questions` as `tbpa` ON `tbpda`.`user_id` = `tbpa`.`user_id`  
LEFT JOIN `tb_user_info` as `tbui` ON `tbua`.`user_id` = `tbui`.`user_id`
WHERE `tbpda`.`user_id` = $uid 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) >=`tbpa`.`min_age_required` AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) <= `tbpa`.`max_age_required`
AND IF(`tbui`.`country_of_origin` != 'Any Country',`tbui`.`country_of_origin` = `tbpa`.`country_of_origin`,true)
AND `tbua`.`user_id` != $uid
AND `tbui`.`user_id` NOT IN ($matches)
AND `tbui`.`user_id` NOT IN ($block_users)
AND `tbui`.`user_id` NOT IN ($reported_user)
AND `tbui`.`sex` != '$gender'
AND IF($count > 0,`tbui`.`country` IN ($result),true)
GROUP BY  `tbui`.`user_id`
```

this is working fine the country name is same for two tables but not fetching the record when the `country_of_origin = 'Any Country'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` returns a value, not a new condition to be computed.

So, in your code, you will always get a boolean, `true` or `false` when `tbui.country_of_origin != 'Any Country'` and `true` otherwise.

In the `where`, you have to use:

```
WHERE tbui.country_of_origin = 'Any Country' OR tbui.country_of_origin = tbpa.country_of_origin
```

You might also want to check that `tbpa.country_of_origin = 'Any country'`.

Comment: yeah i have checked for `tbpa.country_of_origin = 'Any country'` this condition it's there